# Cannot read properties of undefined using HubSpot api

Tags: hubspot-api

I am new the the HubSpot custom code api in their workflows and I keep getitng errors when I try testing my code. ANY code and its damn frustrating. So I am trying to build a generic plug and play sample from th web to see if it is something stupid I am doing but Im still getting it.

The error Im getting is:

2023-03-22T17:30:09.266Z    INFO    ******* got this far
2023-03-22T17:30:09.267Z    ERROR   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')
at /var/task/file.js:21:36
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

and I can see where it is getting to as I have put in a console.log check message and it looks as though it is failing on the properties and I can't figure out why.

the following is my code:

```
// The following snippet applies to the Deal object, but can be modified to calculate a property on any         Object 
// This snippet requires 3 custom properties created in HubSpot: 
// "Start Date" (date) / "End Date" (date) / "Duration" (number)

const hubspot = require('@hubspot/api-client');
exports.main = (event, callback) =\> {

// Set up the HubSpot API client
    const hubspotClient = new hubspot.Client({
        accessToken: process.env.secretName
    });

// Use the client to pull information relating to the currently enrolled deal
hubspotClient.crm.deals.basicApi.getById(event.object.objectId, \["start_date","duration",\])
.then(results =\> {

 // Store properties in variables

  console.log("******* got this far");
                                                             
     let startDate = results.body.properties.start_date;
     let duration = results.body.properties.duration;

  // Calculate the end date from the variables input
     let d = new Date(startDate)
     let i = parseInt(duration)
     let r= new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()+i))
     r= r.getTime()


       callback({
  // Store the calculated date in a workflow output - don't forget to copy that value to your "End    date" property
         outputFields: {
           end_date: r
         }
       });
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
     });
 }
```

I have also pasted my other properties as well.

[properties screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFWWZ.png)

This should simply grab some values and place them in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to take the body out of the line as below:

```
  //let startDate = results.body.properties.start_date;
  //let duration = results.body.properties.duration;
  let startDate = results.properties["start_date"];
  let duration = results.properties["duration"];
```